# Unable to connect to Gmail using PHP

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I try to connect to my gmail account using php, but the script is hanging at imap_open, leaving my browser waiting for an answer:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'Username';
$password = 'Password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

// Code never reaches this point
```

Any idea if I need to configure anything on my gmail account side, on the php server or if the script is wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have IMAP enabled in your GMail account? See [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018) for more information and how to enable it.

Comment: Does your provider firewall IMAP?  This is pretty common.

Comment: IMAP is well enabled on the account, however I will check with the provider if an IMAP firewall is active, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must to enable the IMAP connection in gmail account which one you want to connect through IMAP.

Enable IMAP in your Gmail settings

Sign in to Gmail.
Click the  gear in the top right.
Select Settings.
Click Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
Select Enable IMAP.
Click Save Changes.

Comment: I am already accessing my gmail as imap from a native client on the computer or on the iPhone...

Comment: create one php file with <?php 
phpinfo();
?> then run at server . Check IMAP function is enabled or disabled in your server.